# JavaScript into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm working in WordPress.

I have this code:

```
<?php echo $options['phonenumber']; ?>
```

Which works and it's showing the phonenumber typed in admin.
What I want is to show a specific number if in admin the field phonenumber is empty.

I tried this:

```
<?php
    $defaultphone="9999";
if (function_exists( $options['phonenumber'] )) {
    echo $options['phonenumber'];
} else {
    echo $defaultphone; 
}
?>
```

and it's not working. It shows only 9999 even if I insert a number in admin.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: try not `function_exists( $options['phonenumber'] )` but `!isset(  $options['phonenumber'] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function_exists` is not the right way to test for this. You may want to try

```
if ($options['phonenumber']) {
```

instead. Note that the exact test may depend on exactly how $options is populated.